# Apk doesn't exists

Tags: android, apk

I have a problem with my Android project. Until now, I haven't got any problem with it, but today, after some install on my device, I couldn't run it. Everytime when I want to run it, or make apk from it, it writes that project has compilation errors. apk doesn't exists. But the apk is in the bin directory, so I don't know why it is not good.

Please help if you can, because I tried the project - clean method, and fix project properties too.

Comment: I have tried it with signed apk, but it is the state. Thanks

Comment: Just like console and logcat, there is 1 tab for 'Problems'. Can you copy paste the info what you see there ? (Copy-Paste ONLY the errors, not the warnings)

Answer (score 2):

Delete the `.apk` file and the binaries in the `/bin` folder, then clean the project.

Comment: Your project contains error(s) please fix them before running your application. Only this message, no error marks.

Comment: When I try to export is as signed package:
Project has compilation error(s)!
MyGame/bin/mygame.apk does not exists!

Comment: did you delete the `.apk` from within Eclipse, or from an external file explorer?

Comment: If not, do so, and then come back to Eclipse, right-click on the poject, click refresh, and then clean it again.

Comment: Yes I have deleted it from file explorer, then refresh and clean project, but it is the same as before.

Comment: `Right click on the project -> Android tools -> Run Lint: Check for common errors` check this, probably shows something interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Run the avd manager . There displays the available versions on your avd and their we can identify tick mark our valid android virtual device. If your version of your avd is correct then the tick mark is displayed as green or else red. First check it. After that i will help further.